# prestashop 1.6 display quantity in product list

Tags: themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hello I'm creating theme for prestashop 1.6.
I want to display quantity and additional data like size on products listing (right beside add to basket).

Still i copy and paste part that display data from product but still cant see required data.

Any one have any idea were i have to change tpl to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

In product-list.tpl you can use `{$product.quantity}` for Quantity.

What do you mean by size ?
If you mean width, height and depth of the package size you can set in the Shipping tab, you can use `{$product.width}`, `{$product.height }` and `{$product.depth }`

Answer (score 0):

You have variables name in product.tpl
Quantity of a product in product.tpl : $product->quantity

If you want to call it in product.tpl : {$product->quantity}

Comment: I struggle with your English. Please try to use punctuation, as well as code formatting (`backticks`). Maybe include a code example to clarify your answer.

Comment: Try to insert anywhere in product.tpl : 
`{$product->quantity}`
_Except in a smarty condition like_ `{if} {/if}`